# Run WEBrick 1.3.1 in background with jruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, webrick, httpserver

I have a simple WEBrick "listener" which handles requests coming from GitLab which I run with jruby:

```
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3030)
server.mount_proc '/' do | req, res |
    Run.new(req.body)
end

trap 'INT' do
    server.shutdown
end

trap 'TSTP' do
   server.shutdown
end

server.start
```

Everything is working perfectly but the fact that I am unable to get this running in the background, so every time I close shell I loose the service, anyway to run this in background?

Answer (score 0):

start with probably the simplest thing you could do (with Ruby in general) :

`nohup jruby server.rb &`